# How to programmaticaly create task on windows

Tags: windows, task

There are some programs which can create some tasks for windows.
I need to create an exe file or batch file which will run, take some xml file(exported task by windows task manager) and create task.
The program Elevated Shortcut can do what I need, but i need to do the same with some command or by running the exe file, no user interface.

The commands like 
schtasks.exe /create /tn MyTask /xml "C:\MyTask.xml" /f
NOT WORKING.

Hope someone can help.
Thank you.

Comment: *"NOT WORKING"* is not a problem statement. Why do you believe that the task scheduler doesn't fit your requirements?

Comment: I just need to to that from my program. I can't say the user to do that manually after he installed my program :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. To add the task the app must have administrator rights.